# Adding and subtract complex numbers using OOP structure

Tags: java, oop, complex-numbers

I have here a code that should print the sum and difference of two complex numbers. The instructions given are:
make the methods `add`, `subtract`, and `print` to be `void` and 
test using the constructor's object.

```
public class Complex {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public double real;
    public double imag;
    public String output = "";

    public Complex(double real, double imag){
        this.real += real;
        this.imag += imag;
    }

    public Complex(){
        real = 0;
        imag = 0;
    }

    public double getReal(){
        return real;
    }

    public void setReal(double real){
        this.real = real;
    }

    public double getImag(){
        return imag;
    }

    public void setImag(double imag){
        this.imag = imag;
    }

    public void add(Complex num){
        this.real = real + num.real;
        this.imag = imag + num.imag;
    }

    public void subtract(Complex num){
        this.real = real - num.real;
        this.imag = imag - num.imag;
    }

    public void print(){
        //
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Complex c1 = new Complex(4.0, 8.5);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(8.0, 4.5);

        c1.add(c2);
        c1.subtract(c2);
        c1.print(); //expected answer 12.0 + 13.0i
                                    //-4.0 - 4.0i
    }

}
```

The expected answers are 12.0 + 13.0i and -4.0 - 4.0i. Please help me with the method `print`. Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? Use `System.out.println()`, possibly with `String.format()`

Comment: off topic. why you adding values in constructor. why not simply assign them?

Comment: System.out.println(real + " " + imag +"i");

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I tried that already but the only output is 4.0 + 8.5i.

Comment: It's the correct output: c1.add(c2) => 12+13i. then c1.subtract(c2)=> 12+13i-(8+4.5i)=4+8.5i... In fact, you are adding then subtracting the same value at c1, so in the end c1 is left unmodified

Comment: Is the problem really with your print() method? If you're getting the wrong output, it sounds like you need to fix your add and subtract and other methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not what you're looking for, but to make the number be printed 
isn't enough to make something like this in your print method?

System.out.print("The number is: " +real +"+i" +imag);

Comment: I tried that already but the only output is 4.0 + 8.5i. The expected answers are 12.0 + 13.0i and -4.0 - 4.0i.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void print(){
     if(this.imag <0){
      System.out.println(this.real+" "+this.imag+"i");
     }
     if(this.imag >0){
      System.out.println(this.real+"+"+this.imag+"i");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly use print merhod. if you want to see correct result you need to rewrite add method like this:

```
public void add(Complex num, Complex num2){
    this.real = num.real + num2.real;
    this.imag = num.imag + num2.imag;
}
```

rewrite subtract method also.

```
public void subtract(Complex num){
    this.real = real - num.real;
    this.imag = imag - num.imag;
}
```

Now main method look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(4.0, 8.5);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(8.0, 4.5);
        Complex result = new Complex(8.0, 4.5);
        result.add(c1,c2);

        result.print();

        result.subtract(c1,c2);
        result.print();
```

print method as I told previously look like:

```
public void print(){
    System.out.println(real + " " + imag +"i");
}
```

Explanation:

In your code you have error. You add c2 to c1 and then subtract c2 frim c1 and then print result. Mathematically this looks like : c1= c1+c2-c2;