# Java a.add(b) method

Tags: java, addition

I am working on a project for homework. The test code was given and I basically have to get it working.

I am stuck at creating an `add` method, I cannot figure out how to get one working with the inputs on the test page. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the test code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Test the Complex number class

public class ComplexTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // use Scanner object to take input from users
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the real part of the first number:");
      double real = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter the imaginary part of the first number:");
      double imaginary = input.nextDouble();      
      Complex a = new Complex(real, imaginary);
      System.out.println("Enter the real part of the second number:");
      real = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter the imaginary part of the second number:");
      imaginary = input.nextDouble();      
      Complex b = new Complex(real, imaginary);

      System.out.printf("a = %s%n", a.toString());
      System.out.printf("b = %s%n", b.toString());
      System.out.printf("a + b = %s%n", a.add(b).toString());
      System.out.printf("a - b = %s%n", a.subtract(b).toString());
   } 
}
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
public class Complex {
    private double real;
    private double imaginary;

    public Complex() {
        this(0,0);
    }

    public Complex(double real) {
        this(real,0);
    }

    public Complex(double real, double imaginary) {
        this.real=real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public void setReal(double real) {
        this.real = real;
    }

    public void setImaginary(double imaginary) {
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    public double add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the signature of your add method be something more like

    public Complex add(Complex other)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550771/adding-and-subtract-complex-numbers-using-oop-structure can help

Comment: You also need to override toString() and decide if add(Complex other) will just mutate the called upon Complex object or return a new Complex object that represents the addition of self and other.  Either way, you'll need getters for real and imaginary to get those values from the Complex other argument.

Comment: @jshort You don't need getter methods "to get those values from the `Complex other` argument". The `add` method belongs to `Complex`, so it has full access to all fields of `Complex`, including the fields of an instance other than `this`. It is perfectly fine and appropriate to write `this.real + other.real` inside the `add` method.

Comment: Note: there is no need to call `toString()` when passing an object to `printf` for use with the `%s` format specifier. If the object is not a `String`, `printf` will call `toString()` on it itself.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, you will probably want your `add` method to both take and return a `Complex` object. Try this:

```
public Complex add(Complex other) {
    return new Complex(this.real + other.real, this.imaginary + other.imaginary);
}
```

That will create a new `Complex` instance. To modify in-place, use this:

```
public Complex add(Complex other) {
    this.real += other.real;
    this.imaginary += other.imaginary;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: @RichardTran you're free to use private variables inside the class defining them

Comment: @RichardTran You can access private fields from within the same class.

Comment: With the edit, I would think a "void" signature might be clearer API? It's weird having something other than a "builder" object mutate and also return itself? *shrug*

Comment: @muzzlator It's definitely non-standard, but I've seen it done. There are plug-ins out there that convert all your `void` methods to return `this`. It's not how I would do things, but it fits into the usage in OP's question.

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen that before. Thanks